# Node red multiple msg.payloads

Tags: sqlite, node-red

i got 2 nodes fetching some mqtt data, some temperature and humidity readings. Im trying to pass that info to a sqlite node. On that node i have the following code:

```
var newMsg = {
 "topic": "INSERT INTO ambiente VALUES (null, #thisshouldbetemperature, #thisshouldbehumidity, date('now'), time('now') )"
 }

return newMsg;
```

I try to use a join node but didnt make the work. So, what is the correct way to pass both msg.payload to that function? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `join` node is the correct way to combine the 2 incoming messages. You should use the manual mode and configure it to create a key value object something like this.

[image]

The problem is that your function node is ignoring the incoming data and creating a new message with just a topic set.

The fix for the function node is:

```
msg.topic = "INSERT INTO ambiente VALUES (null, " + msg.payload.temperature + ", " + msg.payload.humidity + " , date('now'), time('now') )";
return msg;
```

This will just update the `msg.topic` and leave the incoming `msg.payload` intact. This assumes that the MQTT messages arrive on topics `temperature` and `humidity`.

Comment: hi thanks for your answer!! now the join part works well, but on the debug of the function i cant get the value, just undefined. my topics are room/temperature and room/humidity . may it be there the error?

Comment: And put a debug node on the output of the `join` node

Comment: mmm not getting it... msg.topic = "INSERT INTO ambiente VALUES (null, " + msg.payload.room/temperature + ", " + msg.payload.room/humidity + " , date('now'), time('now') )";
return msg;    // is giving me a ReferenceError: temperature is not defined (line 1, col 70)

Comment: i need to define temperature? the key (topic) is room/temperature not temperature

Comment: Because the key name has a / you will need to use the alternate method to access the key. `msg.payload['room/temperature']`